# función que copia números en orden inverso c++

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Necesito diseñar una función que copie los números de una lista a otra en orden inverso. Yo envío 2 listas desde main(): int lista1[3]={1,2,3} y int lista2[];

```
int copiarlnv(int *lista1, int *lista2){
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=2;j>=-1; j--){
        int p=lista1[j];
        lista2[j]=p;
        }
        cout<<lista2[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que luego yo veo lista 2 como lista de tres numeros iguales, 3, en lugar cuando necesita mostrarme 3 2 1. Y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Hola, podrías aceptar la respuesta si te fue útil  gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un solo **ciclo for** resuelves tu problema:

```
int j = 0;

for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
   lista2[j] = lista[i];
   j++;
}
```

Como mismo puedes hacer un **ciclo incremental** puedes hacer un **ciclo decremental**.

Aquí recorremos el **arreglo lista** desde la última posición hasta la **0**, o sea lo recorremos en orden inverso y entonces vamos copiando al **arreglo lista2** los elementos del **arreglo lista**, la **variable j** nos sirve como índice para guardar en el **arreglo lista2** los elementos del **arreglo lista** a medida que este se vaya recorriendo.

Comment: Solo haría un pequeño cambio, en vez de declarar fuera la `j` e incrementarla manualmente, nadie te impide usar un bucle con múltiples variables: `for(int i=2, j=0;i>=0;i--, j++)`, incluso usando una única condición, así  la `j` se incrementará tantas veces como se decremente la `i`

Comment: @Benito-B es verdad gracias por la aclaracion, pero me parece q para un usuario novato es mas facil ir paso a paso, pero si, me gusta tu solución